# Java recieving AJAX requests via sockets

Tags: java, ajax, sockets

I have a Java program, and it needs to listen for and handle requests sent to it via AJAX and respond.

Are there any libraries that handle this? If not how would I handle this myself with sockets?

Comment: http://jetty.codehaus.org/jetty/

Comment: hmmm if someones going to ask that this be closed at least comment why =s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ajax works on the http protocol and to handle the call, something such as a webserver would be required. The below links describe about few java servers:

http://www.jibble.org/miniwebserver/

http://jetty.codehaus.org/jetty/

The following link has the complete code of implementation from the scratch if you would like to:

http://fragments.turtlemeat.com/javawebserver.php